# IRC: No Ident response

Tags: java, client, chat, irc

I am currently working on a IRC client written in Java.

As soon as the connection to the server is established I send these messages:

> - /NICK test
> - /JOIN #chat

The first tests went pretty well - the server is responding. But every time it says:

> - NOTICE AUTH :***
> - Checking Ident
> - NOTICE AUTH :***
> - No Ident response
> - ERROR :Closing Link ... (Registration timed out)

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381895/responde-to-no-ident-response-on-irc) that helped a little bit. It says I need to listen on port 113 for a connection and a message to receive and respond to from the IRC-Server. I implemented a ServerSocket that listens on that port, but the server doesn't try to open a connection on port 113. What am I doing wrong?

Heres the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class IdentProtocolThread extends Thread {

private String nick;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private BufferedReader reader;
private BufferedWriter writer;

public IdentProtocolThread(String nick) throws IOException {
    this.nick = nick;

    this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(113);
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        System.out.println("waiting for incoming socket");
        Socket socket = this.serverSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("socket accepted");
        this.initialize(socket);
        System.out.println("reader/writer initialized");

        String line = null;
        while ((line = this.reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}

private void initialize(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
}
}
```

On execution I only get this displayed:

> waiting for incoming socket

Do I need to send some other messages to avoid the ident check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844821/1832966) for references to the underlying IRC protocol; it is somewhat more structured than the `/`-commands you're used to seeing in a client.  The handshake often looks something like this:

```
<< USER foo . . :real name
<< NICK bar
>> :server PING somethinglonghere
<< PONG :somethinglonghere
>> :server 001 bar :Welcome!
<< JOIN #channel
>> :bar!foo@yourhost JOIN #channel
>> :server 332 bar #channel :channel topic
>> :server 353 bar = #channel :@someop +somevoice someuser anotheruser
>> :server 366 bar #channel :End of /NAMES list
```

where `<<` indicates a line of text sent to the server and `>>` indicates a line of text received from the server.  Note also that IRC nominally uses `\r\n` line endings, though a number of servers will accept `\n` too.

Comment: I've tried your first line(`USER ytrezq@myopera.com :ytrezq`) and got `:morgan.freenode.net 461 * USER :Not enough parameters`

Comment: That "foo" there is the user, and the periods are actually arguments.  For instance, "USER prez . . :Zaphod Beeblebrox" followed by "NICK zaphod" if I want to be "zaphod!prez@heartofgold.space"